# How to set the margins of the <Image /> component directly?

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

I use the Next.js `<Image />` component to load the logo in my header. I want to position the component within the header. In short, I need to specify its margin.

```
    <div className={styles.header}>
      <Image src={logo} alt="logo" />
      <nav>navbar</nav>
      <ul>
        <li>opt1</li>
        <li>opt2</li>
        <li>opt3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I know that I can simply place the `<Image />` inside a positioned block, but is there a way to do it directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is not. You can modify many properties by passing `className` prop to `next/image`. But since margin is relative to the wrapper, modifying it won't help you.

What you are trying to do requires setting styles on the wrapper inserted over `img` tag by `next/image`, which currently is not possible (directly). *See [this discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18312) for better insight.*

However, as a workaround (for your particular case) you can add the styles on your header that select the wrapper `div`. Refer: [CSS Combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators)

```css
.header > div {
   margin-left: 2em;
}
```

---

Update: In newer versions you can use the [experimental image component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/future/image) that renders `img` without any wrapper.

Comment: thanks for the tip and clarification!

Answer (score 2):

I think using styled-components is a pretty way.

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import styled from 'styled-components';


const StyledImage = styled(Image)`
  /* your custom style */
  margin: 10px;
`;

and using it: <StyledImage src={image_path} />
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

As [nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) on Image component says you can use `className` for styling the same way as you do with your usual elements.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply class name to the `<Image/>` component. E.g.

```
<Image
  className="dummy-name" 
  src={src} 
  width={2400} 
  height={1598} 
  layout="responsive"/>
```

[Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) has listed some useful properties.